# How to "curl -X POST" with Webhook (or something else)

Tags: webhooks, ifttt

I have a question about ifttt. Im looking for a service that can run a "curl" command to control my GHoma devices.

I don't want to use an extra server for that or something else, because for this solution I could run the command below over my raspberry pi.(but this is not the solution im looking for)

My first idea was to use webhook but it looks it doesn't work with that, or I'm to stupid to get it run.

Hope you can help me with that

```
curl_ghoma_plug1_on: curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type:text/xml' --data '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><v:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:d="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"

xmlns:c="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:v="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><v:Header />

<v:Body><service xmlns="http://www.thinkhome.com.cn/" id="o0" c:root="1"><json i:type="d:string">{"head":{"code":"120"},"body":

{"authentication":{"FUserAccount":"example&#64;gmail.com","FPassword":"123FXXXXXXXXX"},"action":{"FActionType":"5","FActionNo":"123-XXX-XXX","FKeyNum":"0","FAction":"1","FValue":""}}}</json></service></v:Body></v:Envelope>'

http://m.g-homa.com/wsi/action/ActionWebService.asmx
```

Btw. I already tested the option POST but the activity log from IFTTT says **"Applet skipped Unable to make web request. Your server returned a 500"**

My "Body-Part" looks like this

```
{

    "authentication":{

     "FUserAccount":"xxxxxx&#64;gmail.com",

     "FPassword":"123XXXXXXXXXXXX"

    },

    "action":{

     "FActionType":"5",

     "FActionNo":"3XXXX-3XXX-ABXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX",

     "FKeyNum":"0",

     "FAction":"1",

     "FValue":""

     }

 }
```

Comment: Unrelated: `curl -X POST` is an antipattern. POST is implied by your use of `--data`

Comment: If you are using an iOS, shortcuts app can be used to make an HTTP POST to webhooks. [Here](https://www.macstories.net/ios/how-to-trigger-ifttt-applets-with-ios-12s-new-shortcuts-app-and-siri/) is the steps involved. Skip the first IFTTT-related section. Look at how Shortcuts app can be configured.